# apache logs show tab character as \t from python scripts

Tags: python, apache

In my python programs (django or web.py), i write logs to STDERR. e.g.

```
sys.stderr.write('tab\tcharacter')
```

When serving these programs via Apache, the logfiles has the literal "\t", and NOT a real tab (ascii=9)

If I test this program from a command line, I see real tabs. So it's probably something in Apache.

Is there a feature in apache logs that converts a tab character to \t ?

Is there a way to work around and see tabs in apache log files?

**EDIT**

i gave it up. Instead of \t i'm using another character for separator...

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
a = "tab" + chr(9) + "character"
sys.stderr.write(a)
```

No?

Comment: Then he still gets `"\\t"`. This doesn't help at all.

Comment: log('--\t--', r'--\t--', r'--\\t--')    --- none of these yields a real tab in the logs.  (just verified, who knows...)

Comment: @BerryTsakala: and what about a var? containing `chr(9)` directly? Or making a raw string with `chr(9)` in it (as in my edited response)?

Comment: @Clodion - you're missing something:  when the same program runs from console, the tabs are expended correctly.   But when Apache is handling the STDERR, then it replaces a real tab with "\t"

Answer (score 0):

Apache is escaping all non-printable characters from your stdout so that it gets one log entry per line. But you could write a script that adds them back. Python has string decoders called "string_escape" and "unicode_escape" that will unescape the string again. Generally "unicode_escape" is more inclusive unless your program is writing a Windows codepage string.

In python2, you decode strings:

```
with open('apache.log') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print line.decode("unicode_escape")
```

But in python3, you decode bytes:

```
with open('apache.log', 'rb') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line.decode("unicode_escape"), end="")
```

Comment: I already wrote a "tail -f" replacement in python with text-filters :) to work around that.  But I'd rather have the tabs there, in real time. Or, did you mean you can install a log filter module inside apache?